# Openlayers 4 WFS & vector select

Tags: openlayers, wfs, vector-layer

I want to convert this project for other use from OL2 to OL4 but I can't convert the code and get back a map,

http://www.trafficorders.uk/

here the OL2 code:

```
  layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("UKMap", "http://www.trafficorders.uk/cgi-bin/wmsmaps", {
    layers: "bgmap"
  }, {
    isBaseLayer: true,
    transitionEffect: 'resize',
    singleTile: false,
    ratio: 1.1
  });

  var areaStyMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
      fill: true,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: "#000000",
      fillColor: "${MapColour}",
      strokeWidth: 1

    }),
    "select": new OpenLayers.Style({
      strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWidth: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF9900",
      label: "${Name}",
      labelOutlineWidth: 3,
      labelOutlineColor: '#ffffff',
      fontSize: "12px",
      fontFamily: "Arial, Courier New",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    })
  });

  var strat = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed();
  var pmproto = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url: "http://www.trafficorders.uk/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/vhosts/trafficorders.uk/httpdocs/maps/wfsareas.map",
    featureType: "la_areas",
    featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver",
    featurePrefix: "ms"
  });
  arealayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("la_areas", {
    strategies: [strat],
    protocol: pmproto,
    styleMap: areaStyMap
  });
```

and here my new code:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://www.traffwebdev.uk/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/vhosts/traffwebdev.uk/httpdocs/hosted/maps/wfsareas.map',
    format: new ol.format.WFS({
      featureType: ["la_areas"],
      featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver",
      featurePrefix: "ms"
    })
  })
});
```

the featureNS seems to do not works, I don't have nothing back while in the old code I have a collection of features.

What I want to achieve is something like this but with WFS instead of geoJson

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html

Comment: what request get's sent to the server in each case?

Comment: well that is all my code, I supposed that the request will be sent automatically? I don't quite understand how OL2 works and how to convert it, there is no such `strategies` in OL4

Comment: i found this https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html but I don't know if it's what I really need. when I load the page a request to http://www.traffwebdev.uk/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/vhosts/traffwebdev.uk/httpdocs/hosted/maps/wfsareas.map is sent automatically but without respond while in OL2 in the live system I have an xml back

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the actual request is different, different versions perhaps, or if the request is the same and the problem lies in handling the response

Comment: well I copied the whole website into the dev domain and changed the code with OL4, mapserver is the same and the map file also. Also what I don't understand is that if you open the URL in OL2 (http://www.trafficorders.uk/cgi-bin..) you have an error but still you have a respond back while in OL4 you just have the 2 filed in the xml file

Comment: I wanted to know What GetFeature request is sent from the OpenLayers clients to trafficorders.uk

Comment: the code in the question is the responsible to make the request and create the map, you can see the whole js code here http://www.trafficorders.uk/js/parkingv1.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find 2 solutions:

- [one using EPSG 27700 for map](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/840d89e3cdcc3519ac5b65e6872c2cc4) (hence the OpenStreetMap cutting on the OSM basemap)
- [the other one using EPSG 3857 for map](https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/9f1558aaf9fcdbff9039cc0131131e74) (slower as a reprojection client side happened)

Normally according to the current code you should use the first solution e.g with map projection EPSG 27700 (surely related to the fact that your map is UK only)

Comment: thanks you very much it almost work, I just have the error `Cannot read property 'getAxisOrientation' of null` I setup the projection and extent in this way `Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:27700',
  getPointResolution: function(r) {
    return r;
  },
  units: 'm'
});
var extent = [0, 0, 700000, 1000000];
projection.setExtent(extent);`

Comment: this is the code I'm using http://www.traffwebdev.uk/hosted/js/host.js

Comment: Simply don't use it this file! This version of Proj4, 1.x  is outdated since years! You need to switch to a recent version of Proj4 (2.x). You can get the required infos in both demos e.g `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.14/proj4.js"></script>` and `<script src="http://epsg.io/27700.js"></script>` If it's just about hosting, download them. FYI, the equivalent of the beginning of your code is in http://epsg.io/27700.js

Comment: whit those links and your code it enters in an infinite loops of requests

Comment: It's somewhere else in your code as both provided demos work. I can't fix bug(s) from your own code, just can help about things described in the perimeter of your question here. Sorry

Comment: I open a new question, btw I don't understand why in your demo you have just few regions displayed instead of all them, in the request to mapserver you have back all of them in the file.

Comment: There was an issue in my code (fixed in the EPSG 27700 demo not in the other at the moment). I have also changed the strategy http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html#.all